# RecyclerView getLeft in LinearLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have been trying to read through the documentation of `LayoutManager` and `LinearLayoutManager` to find `getLeft()/grtRight()/getTop()/getBottom()` methods of the `recyclerview` but no luck. I could only find getPadding**() methods but not get**() methods. Is there a reason for why these methods are not exposed inside `LayoutManagers` ?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? A layout manager has no 'left' or 'right', it is just layouting the views

Comment: The reason is because those methods are view properties; hence they are properties of the widget itself.  You would just use `recyclerView.getLeft()`, etc.